# My WD passport detected but not shown on my computer

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-detection

1TB WD harddisk is detected in laptop but drives not visible on my computer.

Under disk managment drives shown without letters. Right clicking on these drives give 2 options:

1. Delete volume
2. Help.

The same harddisk was running well on the same laptop a day before. It is also showing full size of hard drives, Healthy (Primary Partition) etc. (this happened after harddisk usage by guest). Harddisk is new only (about 5 month usage)

Please suggest:

1. Is there hardware related problem inside harddisk, if so is it repairable?
2. Is there any option to recover data?

Comment: Have you clicked on "help"?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I recovered by using Ubuntu to access and move the data.